# Equation to calculate change in correlation following addition of random variation

Tags: correlation

I am working on problem where I need to determine the correlation coefficient between two datasets after I add random variation to each dataset.

For example, the correlation coefficient between set A and B is 0.97. After I add known random error to each observation in set A and B, the correlation coefficient drops to 0.88. While the result seems intuitive,  I am wondering if there are equations I can use to calculate the revised correlation coefficient (0.88) from the base coefficient (0.97). Is there such a thing as propagation of correlations? It seems I can obtain my answer via simulation but was hoping there may be an equation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do equations!

for convenience purposes, $E[y]=E[x] = 0, \sigma_y = \sigma_x = 1 $

$$
cor(x,y) = \frac {E[xy]-E[x]E[y]} {\sigma_x \sigma_y} =E[xy]
$$

now let's add $y',x'$ noises that are again $E[x']=E[y'] =0$ and $x',y'$ are uncorrelated with all the others.

We can calculate the correlation now:
$$
cor(x+x',y+y') = \frac{E[(x+x')(y+y')] + E[x+x']E[y+y']}{\sqrt{(\sigma_x^2+\sigma_{x'}^2)\cdot(\sigma_y^2+\sigma_{y'}^2)}}
$$
$$
=\frac{E[(x+x')(y+y')]}{\sqrt{(1+\sigma_{x'}^2)\cdot(1+\sigma_{y'}^2)}}
=\frac{E[xy] + E[x'x]+E[y'y]+E[y'x']}{\sqrt{1+\sigma_{x'}^2 +\sigma_{y'}^2+\sigma_{x'}^2\sigma_{y'}^2}}
=\frac{E[xy]}{\sqrt{1+\sigma_{x'}^2 +\sigma_{y'}^2+\sigma_{x'}^2\sigma_{y'}^2}}
=\frac {cor(x,y)}{\sqrt{1+\sigma_{x'}^2 +\sigma_{y'}^2+\sigma_{x'}^2\sigma_{y'}^2}}<cor(x,y)
$$

Comment: Thank you! This is very insightful. What does this equation look like if the standard deviation of x and y are not 1 and the expected values for x and y are not 0?

Comment: First of all your more than invited to try it! but expected values effect is nullified in the numerator so they do not affect the correlation at all. The standard deviation, on the other hand, affects the denominator, it's not complicated though, so you should try it... if your having trouble just say so and I'll include that in the answer :)

Comment: Eureka - I understand! Thank you for the follow-up. I was feeling a bit dense and your response plus an extra cup of coffee was just what I needed. Thank you for being so responsive and helpful.